# convert data formatting in a lua file

Tags: lua, string-formatting

hello i need to convert 720 data sets from a 1 liner to this format below.
Atm i got them in a open office file with each number in a column but i have no idea how i can convert that formatting.

```
12  -8906.071289 560.890564 93.236107 0 test2
13  -846.814636 -526.218323 10.981694 0 southshore
```

to

```
[12] = {
    [1] = "test2",
    [2] = "-8906.071289",
    [3] = "560.890564",
    [4] = "93.236107",
    [5] = "0",
},
[13] = {
    [1] = "Southshore",
    [2] = "-846.814636",
    [3] = "-526.218323",
    [4] = "10.981694",
    [5] = "0",
},
```

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility in Lua.  Run with `program.lua datafile`
where `program.lua` is whatever name you give this file, and `datafile` is, well, your external data file.  Test with just `program.lua`

```
--[[
12  -8906.071289 560.890564 93.236107 0 test2
13  -846.814636 -526.218323 10.981694 0 southshore
--]]

local filename = arg[1] or arg[0]       --data from 1st command line argument or this file
local index,head,tail

print '{'
for line in io.lines(filename) do
  if line:match '^%d+' then
    head, line, tail = line:match '^(%d+)%s+(.-)(%S+)$'
    print('  [' .. head .. '] = {\n    [1] = "' .. tail .. '",')
    index = 1
    for line in line:gmatch '%S+' do
      index = index + 1
      print('    [' .. index .. '] = "' .. line .. '",')
    end
    print '  },'
  end
end
print '}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk program does it:

```
{
    print "[" $1 "] = {"
    print "\t[" 1 "] = \"" $NF "\","
    for (i=2; i<NF; i++) {
        print "\t[" i "] = \"" $i "\","
    }
    print "},"
}
```